# parse version number from file name as python int

Tags: python

What would be a clean way of getting the version number from a filename using python. For example say i have filepath like so:

```
'Z:\\projects\\TEST\\assets\\TEST_PRP_Book\\tasks\\mdl\\TEST_PRP_Book_mdl_v021.max'
```

and I want get the version number as an int value like

```
21
```

As a fail safe if the file is named incorrectly im fine with returning 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is probably just use [regex search](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match) for something like `"\\d+"` (any number of digits) assuming that your filename will not contain other digits. Otherwise, you'll need to write a more complex regex pattern for the edge cases.

Python's int() seems to handle leading zeros just fine, so you could just wrap your regex in that and avoid worrying about them.

Comment: I personally try to avoid regex if I can do with straight python. In this case rfind() and substring will work just fine I think.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the naming convention is always "_v##" then would this work for you:

```
import os

def returnVersionNumber(file):
    fileName, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
    versionDelimiter = fileName.rfind("_v")

    if versionDelimiter == -1:
        return 0
    else:
        return int(fileName[versionDelimiter + 2:])


print returnVersionNumber('Z:\\projects\\TEST\\assets\\TEST_PRP_Book\\tasks\\mdl\\TEST_PRP_Book_mdl_v021.max')
```